# Issue in react-native-pdf library gradle build

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, react-native-pdf

I am getting the following build error when I run `react-native run-android`

**Error**

> Could not resolve all files for configuration
>   ':react-native-pdf:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not find support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0).   Searched in the following
>   locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.1.0/support-v4-26.1.0.aar

The issue is because of 404 error in the jcenter url.

**My Project Level gradle.**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        google()
        configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
        }
    }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

subprojects{
           if ((project.name.contains('react-native-image-picker')) || project.name.contains('react-native-vector-icons')) {
                  buildscript {
                        repositories {
                             jcenter()
                             maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
                         }
                   }
           }
}
```

**My App Level Gradle Build**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' } // Gradle Plugin Portal
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.10.0, 0.99.99]'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.raus"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':rn-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-pdf')
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-orientation')
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-aws-cognito-js')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Comment: Can you show build.gradle file of the project "react-native-pdf"

Comment: Thanks Nakul. But had my jcenter() in allprojects -> repositories was not in the right order. I figured it out and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google() // Jcenter must come after google() -- I only checked buildscript
        jcenter()
        configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
        }
    }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```